# When did Napoleon start to be regarded as a French national hero?

Tags: france, historiography, napoleon

Napoleon was a very controversial figure at the time of his death. A large percentage of French were monarchists and pro-Bourbons. Many others were Republicans or Socialists who were against personal dictatorships.

Instead, in the days of the Great War, he was widely seen as a French national hero, and now that perception is almost unanimous. When and how did this change in public opinion happen?

Comment: Is it national opinion or national politics (or both) involved here?

Comment: During the [First Italian Campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon#First_Italian_campaign)?

Comment: I think he means "after the Borbon Restauration / Napoleon I's death". And, if you think that Louis Napoleon won the French elections in 1848 and had already staged a coup in 1836 on the basis of being a relative of Napoleon I, I would say that while the Borbon regimen did condemn Napoleon I's memory, he remained a national hero for lots of people even then.

Comment: After ["a whiff of grapeshot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/13_Vend%C3%A9miaire#A_whiff_of_grapeshot)

Answer (score 2):

Napoleon's career as a national hero started after his military victories during the "revolutionary wars" in France (Toulon) and Italy.

His next adventure was expedition to Egypt which ended with a humiliating defeat,
but somehow this was not clear to most in France, and they made him a dictator
with strong popular support. The later spectacular victories of the French army very much increased his popularity. He was able to ride on the wave of patriotism.

I understand this seems weird to some people, but one has probably to take into account almost a century of previous continuous British-French wars.
Probably it seemed
to many people that he is able to finally win this competition.

Comment: There was "Napoleon 3"...who started out strong but turned into a total dud...so certainly "Napoleon the Original and Still the Best" definitely "moved up the list" after that disaster.